# global variable in js confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.myclass').click(function({
    that = $(this);  
    standardDelay = setInterval(function() {
        doSomething(that.attr("id"));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Is the global variable `that` can be accessible in other js file? if yes how can I pass $(this) into my setInterval function?

Comment: The code you have will do that already.

Comment: 'that'  should already be accessible inside setInterval .

Comment: initialize it in the click function with var that = $(this); so that it is not available outside click function

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in `(function({`. It has to be `(function(){`. The missing `'` was corrected here, but please make sure your code is also like that.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, a variable initialized with `var` is local to the current code block (and is accessible from the inner code block)

A variable initialized without `var` is global, and can be accessed anywhere, and that should be avoided, unless you really want to do it

So your code can be rewritten to this:

```
$('.myclass').click(function({
    var that = $(this);
    var standardDelay = setInterval(function() {
        doSomething(that.attr("id")); // You can still access `that` here
    }, 1000);
}));
// No, `that` is `undefined` here
```